# Audio Signal Noise: Understanding & Troubleshooting

Tags: usb, audio, noise, signal-integrity, signal-theory

Today, I'm wearing a pair of active headphones for a change.. ( Running on 2x AAA batteries ).
I've hooked them up to a synth and noticed this really annoying monotone  buzz / hum in the background.

I spent some minutes trying to troubleshoot it, and noticed that; if I stick my finger into the empty USB port on the back; the audio signal clears up, instantly.

What's going on? Why does that happen?

Answer (score 1):

The amplifier in the headphones is amplifying the voltage between your head and the cans. This voltage will have lots of mains harmonic pickup from your house wiring. By touching a local voltage reference, you connect (weakly) your head and the amplifier circuit reference voltage, so there is less interfering signal to amplify. It is easy to remove the interfering voltage because its only weakly coupled from the mains in the first place.

There is no safe, easy fix. Earthing yourself is not really a great idea. Better headphones maybe. (they can screen the amplifier, and prevent it picking up spurious signals)

Comment: Why is earthing myself not really a great idea? Is that what's happening when I touch the USB Port?

Comment: Earthing yourself increases the probability of an electric shock being fatal. ESD wrist straps use multiple 10M ohm resistors to reduce this risk as an example. It's OK, but if something else goes wrong, your chances are reduced a little.

Answer (score 0):

Noise control can come down to trial and error sometimes.  Earthing yourself is, as Sean says, a poor idea.  However, you might try doing it through a small capacitor, about 1000 pF might be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Decouple your headphone's amplifier power supply with a somewhat large low ESR cap (a 1000uF tantalum, or low ESR aluminum can should do nicely). You need a larger cap because the frequency you want to decouple is low (60Hz).